# JavaScript target multiple classes in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, var

How can I target multiple classes in a JS selector? Please note that the code below doesn't work with the three classes. It only works with "class-one" as soon as I add more classes I get an error message.

```
var lightboxDescription = GLightbox({
  selector: 'class-one', 'class-two', 'class-three',
  openEffect: 'none',
  closeEffect: 'none'
});
```

Comment: @RobKwasowski Question is tagged jquery-selectors

Comment: Your question pertains to a specific library `Glightbox`. The github page states that `selectors` must be a string. https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox#lightbox-options

Comment: I think what you need is `class-one class-two class-three` with spaces in between

Comment: The main problem with the code you've tried is that it causes a syntax error; try `selector: 'class-one, class-two, class-three',` instead

Comment: Thank you all for your quick feedback! Unfortunately none of the suggested methods seem to work (Uncaught Syntax error...) @mplungjan followed your link but was not able to find a solution. Of course I googled my issue before. Unfortunately for a non-developer, googling many times doesn't help. That's why I try to find answers here. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: `selector: 'class-one, class-two, class-three',` does not work?

Comment: @mplungjan The uncaught Syntax error is gone but the "grouping" of classes doesn't work. Maybe this is a GLightbox related problem. Will try to find a solution on Github and report back here.

Comment: It turns out that "grouping" the classes is not possible. Individual code blocks need to be created for each class.